# difference between cross_val_score and KFold

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I am learning Machine learning and I am having this doubt. Can anyone tell me what is the difference between:-

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
```

and

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
```

I think both are used for k fold cross validation, but I am not sure why to use two different code for same function.
If there is something I am missing please do let me know. ( If possible please explain difference between these two methods)

Thanks,

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `cross_val_score` is a function which evaluates a data and returns the score.
- On the other hand, `KFold` is a class, which lets you to split your data to `K` folds.

So, these are completely different. Yo can make K fold of data and use it on cross validation like this:

```
# create a splitter object
kfold = KFold(n_splits = 10)       
# define your model (any model)
model = XGBRegressor(**params)     
# pass your model and KFold object to cross_val_score
# to fit and get the mse of each fold of data
cv_score = cross_val_score(model,
                           X, y, 
                           cv=kfold, 
                           scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error')
print(cv_score.mean(), cv_score.std())
```

Answer (score 0):

**cross_val_score** evaluates the score using cross validation by randomly splitting the training sets into distinct subsets called *folds*, then it trains and evaluated the model on the folds, picking a different fold for evaluation every time and training on the other folds.

```
cv_score = cross_val_score(model, data, target, scoring, cv)
```

**KFold** procedure divides a limited dataset into k non-overlapping folds. Each of the k folds is given an opportunity to be used as a held-back test set, whilst all other folds collectively are used as a training dataset. A total of k models are fit and evaluated on the k hold-out test sets and the mean performance is reported.

```
cv = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
cv_score = cross_val_score(model, data, target, scoring, cv=cv)
```

where **model** is your model on which you want to evaluate,
**data** is training data,
**target** is target variable,
**scoring** parameter controls what metric applied to the estimator applied and **cv** is the number of splits.